# Как в Python получить временное смещение относительно UTC

Tags: python

В Linux команда `date +"%H:%M:%S %z"` выведет текущее время, в моём случае `17:05:17 +0300` (часовой пояс MSK). Мне нужно это же самое получить на Python. В модуле `datetime` есть возможность форматировать вывод полученного времени с помощью функции `strftime` Я пишу код, который выводит текущее время, но, почему-то, без смещения:

```
import datetime
print(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S %z"))

#17:10:26
```

Подскажите, почему не работает `strftime`, не выводя смещение в +0300, и как это исправить?

Comment: Там вернется пустая строка согласно `(empty string if the object is naive).` из спеки https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes Попробуйте добавить часовой пояс: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7065164/how-to-make-a-timezone-aware-datetime-object-in-python

Comment: Я это видел, но не понял о чём речь. Как-то можно это победить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
import datetime
print(datetime.datetime.now().astimezone().strftime("%H:%M:%S %z"))
```